# Custom dialog disappears when clicking next to it

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to show a custom dialog and force the user to click on whether button one or two.

The problem is that users can use the back button AND if they click on the view that is shown in the background my dialog also disappears.

Why? And how could I prevent this?

```
        final Main t = this;
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.prompt_input_access);
        dialog.setTitle("Title");

        Button cmdLoginAccount = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cmdLoginAccount);
        Button cmdLoginBank = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cmdLoginBank);
        cmdLoginAccount.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loginToBank = true;
                dialog.dismiss();

                Intent intent = new Intent(t, UserMenu.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        cmdLoginBank.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loginToBank = false;
                dialog.dismiss();

                Intent intent = new Intent(t, UserMenu.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
```

Comment: have you though about setting the dialog property cancelable false?

Comment: Thank you. And no obviously I did not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use the [setCanceledOnTouchOutside](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCanceledOnTouchOutside%28boolean%29) method :

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```